# How to execute Netflix-Exhibitor POST REST APIs?

Tags: rest, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, netflix

I need REST APIs for zookeeper and I am referring to https://github.com/Netflix/exhibitor/wiki/REST-Configuration but I'm just not able to execute the POST APIs.

Where can I get the example curl requests using exhibitor. Or can someone please post an example to set the configuration. The curl query is as follows and it requires config as argument.

```
curl -i -X POST "http://hostname:8080/exhibitor/v1/config/set
```

So how would be the final curl request with any configuration as argument. So basically I'm just not able to add arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. :)

```
curl -i -X POST “http://hostname:8080/exhibitor/v1/config/set” -d '{"rollInProgress":false,"rollStatus":"n/a","rollPercentDone":0,"hostname":"hostname.com","serverId":-1,"logIndexDirectory":"","zookeeperInstallDirectory":"","zookeeperDataDirectory":"","zookeeperLogDirectory":"","serversSpec":"","backupExtra":"","zooCfgExtra":{},"javaEnvironment":"","log4jProperties":"","clientPort":0,"connectPort":0,"electionPort":0,"checkMs":0,"cleanupPeriodMs":0,"cleanupMaxFiles":10,"backupMaxStoreMs":0,"backupPeriodMs":0,"autoManageInstances":0,"autoManageInstancesSettlingPeriodMs":0,"observerThreshold":0,"controlPanel":{}}'
```

You have to provide the entire configuration. And change the value of the property you wish to change.